# Is it best practice to inform a potential offer of another? If so, when and how?

Tags: salary, job-offer, negotiation

I'm a technical writer.

I received a contingent job offer letter for a position I am interested in and will pay well. The offer will likely be formally extended after our scheduled in person interview. The offer letter has the usual specifications: at-will, can terminate with or without notice, etc 
I have another position that will likely turn into an offer. This position is remote (ideal) but hasn't yet brought up salary. It's also contractor work, so I imagine the talking to the recruiter about this would be less awkward than if I were a direct employee.

Would it be wise to inform my recruiter of my other offer? I would be willing to earn less to work remotely, but I'd prefer to negotiate as high an offer as possible

Answer (score 7):

I would not inform a recruiter of a possible offer, only an actual offer. If the contingent job offer turns into a real offer and you believe that the other organization(s) can provide an offer that you can seriously consider, then you can inform the recruiter of the other offer to see if they can expedite the process to get you an offer before the first expires. You don't want to risk potential opportunities based on contingent offers.

Answer (score 0):

Part one. Usual realistic view on these matters is:

> you have no job until you signed a contract

It shouldn't matter for the recruiter whether some people promised you anything, and you should treat any offer without written contract as non-existing. Tomorrow any unsigned offer can turn into pumpkin, or you might have an emergency that will prevent you from taking it, or you might decide to change careers. It doesn't matter.

Second part of the question:

> I'd prefer to negotiate as high an offer as possible

Yes, we often would like to make more money. But negotiation process is complicated, and you shouldn't use any leverage until you absolutely sure. Negotiation, to some degree, is a betting process with two actors. You can use any information for making bets, and asking for more money, but be ready that the other party can say "no".

That is why (see part one) you don't say `I want 10% more because that other company Q will pay me 15% more`. The first firm can say "well, okay. Sorry to see you go to Q, bye". If you don't have a hard offer at the time, you are left in the cold.